# Oracle Error using Toad:

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate, toad, create-table

Since a couple of days I can't execute CREATE and TRUNCATE SQL statement using Oracle 12 and Toad 12, ONLY if I terminate my statements with a semicolumn. I've always used the same connections, user and tables, but now I receive these errors while querying:

```
 CREATE TABLE  W_TEST_01
    AS SELECT *
    FROM CFG_FLOW
    WHERE 1 = 2;
```

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
CREATE TABLE W_TEST_01 (PIPPO NUMBER);
```

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

```
TRUNCATE TABLE W_TEST_01;
```

> ORA-03291: Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I guess you have other statements in your query editor that make TOAD behave strangely. The statements **are** valid and will work. Did you try running them with a different SQL client? e.g. SQL\*Plus?

Comment: Do you have any statement above in your editor (which is not terminated by a semicolon)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with parentheses, like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE W_TEST_01
 AS (SELECT * FROM CFG_FLOW WHERE 1 = 2);
```

And if it still does not work, try to see the CTAS Tips
I advise you to take a look at the following [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm)

Hope this can help!

Comment: Those parentheses are totally useless and will not change anything